# MacBook Pro mid2010 SSD optibay upgrade - SandForce?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, apple-inc, macos

I want to replace Superdrive in my MBP mid 2010 with Otpibay SSD.

I have 2nd revision (rev 2/rev B) of mother board replaced due to GPU problems.

Which drive should I consider? I would like to omit 1.5Gbps problem and have some TRIM/Garbage Collector. I wont spend to much money.

I'm thinking about:

1. Intel 520 120GB - SLI SandForce
2. Kingston HyperX 3K SSD 120GB - SLI SandForce
3. Intel 330 120GB - SLI SandForce
4. Samsung 840 Pro 128GB (TLC) - MDX
5. Samsung 840 120GB (TLC) - MDX

Should I worry about SandForce in Optibay?